# Difference between "Active Non-durable Subscibers" and "Active Subscribers" for a particular Topic

Tags: activemq-classic

I'm trying to understand some problems I'm encountering with temporary queues, but I need to clear up some ambiguities in what I'm reading from the Admin Console.

When I look at my list of subscribers, there are 272 "Active Non-Durable Topic Subscribers"

When I look at the "Active Subscribers for ActiveMQ.Advisory.TempQueue", there are none.

There are 272 open connections, and 272 consumers for "ActiveMQ.Advisory.TempQueue"

Why don't I see the non-durable subscribers for the specified queue?

Comment: This question relates to a problem with flooded connections: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7805161/broker-network-flooded-with-unconsumed-activemq-advisory-tempqueue-messages
It may be due to consumers not acknowledging the consumption of messages.

Answer (score 1):

ActiveMQ.Advisory.* are topics to publish metadata about activity in the broker.
That is used in "network of brokers" configuration (among other things).

You are looking for info about your Temp queues, not the advisories for the Temp queues. You may be able to see such info using jmx (jconsole) or by actually subscribing to the advisory topics (by writing a program to do so)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm actually trying to find information relating to the 272 open Advisory.TempQueue connections that shouldn't still be there -- (There are no subscribers on the associated temp queues).